# Query-powered listbox in MS Access form: Selection only visible when matched by query

Tags: sql, ms-access, listbox

I've got a 1:1 relationship between, let's simply call them objects and persons. Every object can have zero or one person. The object has a composite primary key consisting of the object group id and the object id.
Now my users want a convenient way to fill in missing data, so I've created a form that shows all objects without assigned persons. The form is a datasheet with three columns: the group id, the object id and the person key (which is of course empty for all rows when the form is opened).

Because it is very likely that some object will have the same person as some other object from the same group, I created the person id field as a listbox, powered by a query that returns all persons for the currently selected group, so the users can simply add them via a dropdown menu. The form control containing the group id is referenced from within the query, and the listbox is requeried when the selection changes.

So far it works. My problem is now, when I select any object of another group after I assigned a person, the cell content with the assigned person disappears. I assigned persons to several objects for testing and noticed that the person column shows only assigned persons for the group of the currently selected object. If I select an object from another group, they disappear (and the persons of the other object appear). If I again select an object from the same group, the assigned person is there again.
So the assigned persons are only visible if the result of the query for the respective row contains them.

The data is saved though. The assigned persons are saved to the object table immediately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019124/change-control-source-only-selected-combo-box-in-continous-form/13019266#13019266

Comment: Thank you. I've added another column just for displaying the assigned person. The previous field is now only used to select one. The problem is now that the new column shows the person id, but it should show the person name (but of course store the id in the table). What would be the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: How you approach the problem depends very much on how your data works. The new column can be based on a query joining your main table with the name table, so that it shows name or it can be a dlookup against the name table.