# using checkbox in subform in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to use a checkbox in a subform to show if the payment has been made or not and want to make it editable from the subform.

The problem is if I check or uncheck the checkbox in the subform other rows are also affected and the data in the original table is changed. How can I avoid this?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: You clearly have an unbound control. These are problematic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019124/change-control-source-only-selected-combo-box-in-continous-form/13019266#13019266

Comment: thank you for your response and the link but I didn't understand **"You can set various properties of the change combo with conditional formatting to make it all prettier. "** Sorry, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: You are not using a combo, so it does not all apply. The point is that you have an unbound control. Use a bound control.

Comment: If your subform is displaying records from a table rather than a query then you should be able to add a "yes/no" field to the underlying table and then add that field to your subform. As @Fionnuala says, you need to use a "bound" control. This simply means making sure your subform's recordsource is set to the table that has your "yes/no" field. This is done in design view for your subform > property sheet > data tab > recordsource and selecting this table. It's then just a case of clicking the "Add existing fields" button and dragging accross your "yes/no" field to the subform.

Comment: The subform is displaying records from a query and the check box is bound. So, is the query the reason for my problem?

Comment: It is unlikely that the query is the problem unless it has some fancy set up. Try creating a rough form using the form wizards and see how that works. You could also post the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

create another table. I called mine `Selection_Table` with a `selection` field (checkbox) and field `RecordID` (as FK).

You can then use this in the subform. Then VBA can be used to select `recordID` from `Selection_Table` where `selection`=1.

on my close form I also have the following code, to ensure future occasions are not affected by current selections.

```
db.execute(DELETE * FROM Selection_Table)
```